# Ideal and maximum page size for a mobile site?

Tags: mobile, filesize

What is the ideal and absolute maximum page size for a mobile version of a website. I'm talking about file size not screen size.

Comment: There is no correct answer, and "correct" answers will change over time as mobile networks improve on availability and speed. Ask yourself these questions instead: "What are my users average connections like?" "How long are my users willing to wait for a page to load?"

Answer (score 3):

What is your target audience? In many countries there already fast and cheap mobile network. It's not a problem to download 100-200kb. But you must reduce file as much as you can. Throw out all images and javascript you don't need on mobile version.

Answer (score 1):

According to W3C Mobile Web Best Practices http://www.w3.org/TR/mobile-bp/#PAGE_SIZE_LIMIT

> Ensure that the overall size of page is appropriate to the memory
>   limitations of the device.
>
> 5.3.2.3 What to test
>
> PAGE_SIZE_USABLE Machine Test: Measure the total size of the markup
>   for a page; check that it does not exceed 10 kilobytes for the Default
>   Delivery Context.
>
> Human Test: Check that the page is still usable (e.g. not cut in the
>   middle of a sentence, just before the end of a section, and so on).
>
> PAGE_SIZE_LIMIT Machine Test: Measure the total size of markup and
>   images for a page; check that it does not go over the allowed size for
>   the device - 20 kilobytes for the Default Delivery Context.

But in this Smartphone Era it's not possible always so just try to keep as low as possible you can.

Answer (score -3):

ideal would be 1kb, absolute maximum I would say 3Mb